# Not able to read any data from Bluetooth device in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream

I am having a bluetooth device . Basically i want my app to connect to the device and receive the data it sends.However so far i am able to connect to the bluetooth device,but i am not able to receive any inputs from it .

here is my problem:

i) DataInputStream.available() always return 0.

ii) If i use any breakpoint on line
bytes = input.read(buffer);    // This will freeze doesn't show anything.
and line below it never executes

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread{

    final String TAG="ConnectThread";
    private ReadThread mReadThread = null;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    private boolean isDeviceConnected;


    public final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket = null;
    Handler mHandler;
    BluetoothDevice bTdevice;
    private DataInputStream mReadData = null;



    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice bTdevice, Handler mHandler) {
        super();
        this.bTdevice = bTdevice;
        this.mHandler = mHandler;

        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        BluetoothSocket socket;
        try {
            socket = bTdevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            System.out.println("**** Socket created using standard way******");
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            mmSocket = socket;


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice

        try {

            BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            if (adapter != null) {
                adapter.cancelDiscovery();
                Log.i("***Bluetooth Adapter**", "Bluetooth Discovery Canceled");
            }

            if (mmSocket != null) {

                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.i("***Socket Connection Successful**", "Socket Connection Successful");
                isDeviceConnected = true;

                mReadData = new DataInputStream(mmSocket.getInputStream());
                Log.i("***Read data**", "" + mReadData);



                if (mReadThread == null) {
                    mReadThread=new ReadThread(mReadData,mmSocket);
                    mReadThread.start();
                }


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("***Error**", "Socket Connection failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
                isDeviceConnected = false;
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        // mHandler.obtainMessage(DisplayBtdataActivity.SUCCESS_CONNECT,mmSocket).sendToTarget();

    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }





    // Read the data from device

    private class ReadThread extends Thread {

        /** The input. */
        private DataInputStream input;

        /**
         * Constructor for ReadThread.
         * 
         * @param input
         *            DataInputStream
         */
        private BluetoothSocket mSocket;

        public ReadThread(DataInputStream input, BluetoothSocket socket) {
            this.input = input;
            this.mSocket = socket;
        }

        /**
         * Method run.
         * 
         * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
         */
        public synchronized void run() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "ReadThread run");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer store for the stream
                int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
                bytes = input.available(); // always return 0
                // bytes = mReadData.readInt();
                Log.i("***Bytes  data**", "" + bytes);// print 0
                Log.i("***Data input stream**", "" + input); // Here input is not null

                if (input != null) {
                    Log.i("***hello world**", "...");
                    while (isDeviceConnected) {
                        try {

                            bytes = input.read(buffer);     // this code never executes 

                            Log.i("**bytes data**", " " + bytes);

                            if (input != null) {
                                int len = input.readInt();
                                Log.i(TAG, "Response Length: " + len);

                                if (len > 65452) {// Short.MAX_VALUE*2
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Error: Accesory and app are not in sync.");
                                    continue;
                                }

                                Log.d(TAG, "Response Length: " + len);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Reading start time:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                                byte[] buf = new byte[len];
                                Log.d(

                                        TAG, "input.available() " + input.available());
                                if (input.available() > 0) {

                                    input.readFully(buf);
                                    System.out.println("Output:=");


                                }

                                Log.d(TAG, "Reading end time:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                            isDeviceConnected = false;

                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                isDeviceConnected = false;
                Log.e(TAG, "catch block 3 " + e.toString());

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find solution for your question?

Comment: Nope , i haven't found it yet

Answer (score 1):

In `ReadThread.Run()` - you have to move the code

```
bytes = input.available (); // Always return 0
```

into while loop

1, you use `input` before checking for null `if (input! = null)`

2, Data is sent continuously and is a high probability that when running thread do not come any data, so therefore you have to give `input.available bytes = ();` into a while loop.

3, You can try to modify data processing. In principle, quickly read the data in the temporary buffer, and then move to MainBuffer and then manipulated with it. An example is in  `c # .net Xamarin`, but just for an example :

```
    private const int BTLPacketSize = 1024;
    private const int BTLdataSize = 65536;
    private System.Object InternaldataReadLock = new System.Object();
    private System.Object dataReadLock = new System.Object();
    private byte[] InternaldataRead = new byte[BTLPacketSize];//posila 64Byte pakety (resp. 62, protoze 2 jsou status bytes)
    private byte[] TempdataRead = new byte[BTLPacketSize];
    private byte[] dataRead = new byte[BTLdataSize];//Tyto pameti pouzivaji cursorc -> musim ohlidat preteceni pameti//Max. prenos rychlost je 115200 b/s. 
    private bool continueRead = true;

    public override void Run()
    {
        while (continueRead)
        {
            try
            {
                int readBytes = 0;
                lock (InternaldataReadLock)
                {//Quick reads data into bigger InternaldataRead buffer and next move only "received bytes" readBytes into TempdataRead buffer
                    readBytes = clientSocketInStream.Read(InternaldataRead, 0, InternaldataRead.Length);
                    Array.Copy(InternaldataRead, TempdataRead, readBytes);
                }
                if (readBytes > 0)
                {//If something reads move it from TempdataRead into main dataRead buffer a send it into MainThread for processing.
                    lock (dataReadLock)
                    {
                        dataRead = new byte[readBytes];
                        for (int i = 0; i < readBytes; i++)
                        {
                            dataRead[i] = TempdataRead[i];
                        }
                    }
                    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                    dataBundle.PutByteArray("Data", dataRead);
                    Message message = btlManager.sourceHandler.ObtainMessage();
                    message.What = 1;
                    message.Data = dataBundle;
                    btlManager.sourceHandler.SendMessage(message);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                if (e is Java.IO.IOException)
                {
                  //.....
                }
            }
        }
    }
```